# Product of immersions is immersion?

Tags: differential-geometry

If $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, let's define immersions $f\colon U\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g\colon V\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, if I define
$$h\colon U\times V\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$$
With $h((u,v))=(f(u),g(v))$, then it is an immersion too? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, because $ Dh = Df \oplus Dg $ and the direct sum of two injective linear maps is injective. More explicitly,

$$ Dh = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial v} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} Df & 0 \\ 0 & Dg \end{pmatrix}$$

where $Df$ is the partial derivatives matrix of $f$ with respect to the $u^i$-variables, $Dg$ is the partial derivatives matrix of $g$ with respect to the $v^i$ variables, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ is the partial derivatives matrix of $f$ with respect to the $v^i$ variables (which vanishes, as $f$ is independent of $v^i$), etc.

Comment: Why it lets that $Dh=Df\oplus Dg$? It looks obvious, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois: I've added some details.